# Running multiple async tasks returns task to wrong handler

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I create several picture objects that each download their own image. But frequently, the same image shows up for several (or all) of the objects.

```
public class Picture {

private String userID;
private String fileName;
private String baseURI;
private Bitmap img;

public Picture () {
    this.userID = "";
    this.fileName = "";
    this.baseURI = "";
}

/**
 * Retrieves the UUID of the User
 *
 * @return - String
 */
public String getUserID() {return userID;}
public void setUserID(String _userID) {userID = _userID;}


/**
 * Retrieves the Filename of the Picture
 *
 * @return - String
 */
public String getFileName() {return fileName;}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;

    //Don't retrieve a file from the server if the filename is empty or it is a placeholder
    if (fileName != "" && fileName != "NoNewPicure" && fileName != "NewPicture") {

        new RetrieveImageTask(getFileNameURI(), img) {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                setPreview(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}

private URI getFileNameURI() {
    return URI.create(baseURI.concat(fileName));
}
private void setBaseURI(String baseURI) {
    this.baseURI = baseURI;
}

/**
 * Accesors for preview image
 * @return - Image
 */
@Bindable
public Bitmap getPreview() {return img;}
public void setPreview(Bitmap img) {
    this.img = img;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.preview);
}

private static class RetrieveImageTask extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Bitmap> {
    static URI uriString;
    static Bitmap myBitmap;
    private Exception exception;

    RetrieveImageTask(URI uri, Bitmap bitmap) {
        uriString = uri;
        this.myBitmap = bitmap;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URI... src) {
        try {
            Log.e("src",uriString.toString());
            URL url = new URL(uriString.toString());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
}
```

In code the images are called from a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Picture pic = new Picture();
    pic.fromJSON(json_data);
    result.add(pic);
}
```

It appears as though when the Async task returns, several (or all) of the handlers fire. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried adding in this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    URI thisURI = getFileNameURI();
    if (uriString.equals(thisURI)) {
        setPreview(result);
    }
}
```

But then only one Picture object actually gets an image.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple after hearing Another brick in the wall. You can't have any pudding if you don't eat your meat! I can't have my bitmap if the file hasn't downloaded. But I CAN put my bowl where the pudding is going to be so that after I eat my meat, I can eat my pudding. I changed my AsynTask like such:

```
    private class RetrieveImageTask extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Boolean> {
    public URI uriString;
    public Picture pic;

    RetrieveImageTask(URI uri) {
        uriString = uri;
    }
    protected Boolean doInBackground(URI... src) {
        try {
            Log.e("src",uriString.toString());
            URL url = new URL(uriString.toString());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
            pic.setPreview(bitmap);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Note the public variables in the class wrapper. Now when I call my task (code changed from above):

```
        RetrieveImageTask task = new RetrieveImageTask(getFileNameURI());
        task.pic = this;
        task.execute();
```

my bowl will be where the pudding is going to be. IE. I put the calling object as a variable in the private AsyncTask class which populates what I need when it is finished running. :D My bowl of pudding is full after I eat my meat!!!!